# Run the location latitude and longitude function to get the city and country on a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, latitude-longitude, geopandas

There is a function which works well when individual coordinates of the latitude and longitude are given.

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="geoapiExercises")
def city_state_country(coord):
    location = geolocator.reverse(coord, exactly_one=True)
    address = location.raw['address']
    city = address.get('city', '')
    state = address.get('state', '')
    country = address.get('country', '')
    return city, state, country
print(city_state_country("30.930508, 75.8419883"))
```

I want to run this function my dataframe and want to get the output of state in the next column like this

```
ID  latitude     longitude       
1    30.930508    75.8419883     
2     Nan          Nan
3    13.1674503   80.2051151
```

What is required is corresponding to each ID, lat and longitude the function should and give the output as below:

**Note** - function takes just one comma seperated argument of latitude and longitude

```
ID  latitude     longitude     Location     
1    30.930508    75.8419883    state1 
2     Nan          Nan          no coordinate
3    13.1674503   80.2051151    state2
```

**Updated Code**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('C:\\....\\Latitude longitude detail.xlsx')

from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="geoapiExercises")


def city_state_country(coord):
    try:
        location = geolocator.reverse(coord, exactly_one=True)
        address = location.raw['address']
        city = address.get('city', '')
        state = address.get('state', '')
        country = address.get('country', '')
        return city, state, country
#print(city_state_country("30.930508, 75.8419883"))

    except ValueError:
     return(0)

df['Location'] = (df[['latitude', 'longitude']].astype(str)
                   .apply(lambda row: city_state_country(', '.join(row)),
                          axis=1)
                 )
```

The above code does not run. Please point out the error
Any leads would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

IIUC,

```
df['Location'] = (df[['latitude', 'longitude']].astype(str)
                   .apply(lambda row: city_state_country(', '.join(row)),
                          axis=1)
                 )
```

Comment: function takes just one comma seperated argument of latitude and longitude so float numbers of both column should be comma seperated

Comment: please check now

Comment: As per your suggestion after execution it threw ValueError. Once did the exception handling for that it ran in an infinite time. Updating the code in the question please have a look .

Comment: check `df[['latitude', 'longitude']].astype(str).apply(', '.join)`

Comment: Taking consideration of your suggestion and tweaking my script as updated the script ran it took nearly 20 mins for the the code to run and fetch the location for 2200 rows which is indeed time complex script but however it ran so better